# Django - unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'HttpResponseRedirect' and 'unicode'

Tags: django, url

I have login view:

```
def login_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/%s/'%username) 
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Aktywacja konta nie została zakończona")
    else:
        return HttpResponse('invalid login')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^login/',
   "social.views.login_view",
   name='login_view'),
```

template:

```
  <form method="post" action="{% url login_view %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_username">Login:</label> <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Hasło:</label> <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />
  </form>
```

But i getting:

```
TypeError at /accounts/login/
unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'HttpResponseRedirect' and 'unicode'
```

str() function do not help. All usernames could contain only ASCII characters. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning the HttpResponseRedirect?  And the error looks like it was because you had the last paren on the HttpResponseRedirect before the `%`.  The accepted answer wouldn't change anything, just probably made you put the paren in the right spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you store the string in a variable you'd give to HttpResponseRedirect later?

```
foo = "/profile/%s/" % username
HttpResponseRedirect(foo)
```

Comment: Because I don;t know that it could help, but it help. Thanks.